# i have 2 role in codeigniter admin and user when using admin then ajax gives response but in other role it goes in success but controller not response

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

**Script code**

```
<script>
$('#room_type_id').on('change', function()
{
    var id=this.value; //or alert($(this).val());
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/bookings/get_room_plans') ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: {'id':id},
            success: function(result) {
                $("#room_type_plan").find('option').remove().end().append(result);
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

**Codeigniter controller code**

```
    public function get_room_plans()
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $plans = $this->room_type_model->get_plans($id);
        $data="<option value='0'>-- Select Plan --</option>";
        foreach($plans as $p)
        {
          $data .= "<option value='".$p['price']."'>".$p['plan_name']." - ".$p['price']."</option>";
        }
        echo $data;
    }
```

I can not understand while code is same for both roles.Please slove it.

Comment: what is your issue , please explain???

Comment: you can get the `var id=this.value;` of both admin & users?

Answer (score 0):

```
 url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/bookings/get_room_plans') ?>",
```

If you have an user controller please make sure you are calling it. if get_room_plans() is only supposed to be in admin controller, then var_dump $plans to see whats the issue

Comment: No there is same code for both user and admin only role is different

Comment: Please var_dump the $plans and $id var to see what's being sent from ajax to controller `var_dump($plans); exit();`